# .htaccess redirect domain alias to specific page

Tags: .htaccess

The company I work for is opening three restaurants, one has a different name than the others. The site is the same except logos and content. For this reason I've set up a domain alias and it all works fine.

- domain1.com = domain2.com
- domain1.com/example1/ = domain2.com/example1/

However, they'd like me to redirect domain2.com so that, instead of the domain1.com homepage, people are sent to domain2.com/example1/

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example1/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/example1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example1/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/example1/ [R=302,L]
```

This works... sort of.

- http://domain2.com/ successfully redirects to http://www.domain2.com/example1/
- http://domain1.com/example1/ successfully redirects to http://www.domain2.com/example1/

**BUT!** Not entirely...

Examples:

When HTTP_HOST is 'http://domain2.com' this works

- domain2.com to www.domain2.com/page/   (WORKS)
- domain2.com to domain2.com/page/   (REDIRECT LOOP)

When HTTP_HOST is 'http://www.domain2.com'

- www.domain2.com to domain2.com/page/   (WORKS)
- www.domain2.com to www.domain2.com/page/   (REDIRECT LOOP)

Comment: Comments lack formatting... I've updated my question with examples.

Comment: Negative, it's a wordpress site so the pages aren't located in any directory. What I want to do is maintain the functionality of a domain alias while still redirecting domain2.com to a specific page. If that makes sense.

Comment: I've been using a program called Fiddler to monitor the HTTP requests and what not and it shows that, after the initial 302 redirect, it just continues to do 302 redirects until it times out. I've got to be messing it up some where...

Comment: I've got it figured out I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally got it working.

I've updated my htaccess to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/example1/ [R=302,L]
```

So the trick ended up being:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

I read that %{REQUEST_URI} always contains a leading slash, it's never empty, so by checking if it only contains that I was able to straighten out my redirects.

Now, if HTTP_HOST is www.domain2.com

- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$ [NC] = **TRUE**
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ = **TRUE**
- Redirect!

And, if HTTP_HOST is www.domain2.com/example1/

- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$ [NC] = **TRUE**
- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ = **FALSE**
- No Redirect! Woo!