# Forwarding a domain alias to a page on a primary domain with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, plesk

SO, I have read several similar questions and responses on how to make this work, but I have not been able to make my specific situation behave as expected.

Site is a Wordpress install on a Plesk (Obsidian) server.

domainA.com has DNS pointed to domainB.com IP; domainA.com is set up as an alias of domainB.com in Plesk

Here is what I've been trying (.htaccess on domainB):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainB.com/page/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

[.htaccess redirect domain alias to specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220875/htaccess-redirect-domain-alias-to-specific-page)

Expected behavior: domainA.com routs to domainB.com/page

Actual behavior: domainA.com routs to domainB.com/

I have also tried (.htaccess on domainB):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domainB\.com
RewriteRule .* /page/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

[.htaccess redirect specific domain to specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988471/htaccess-redirect-specific-domain-to-specific-page)

with the same result.

(Also a bit unsure if the correct incoming request is a {HTTP HOST} or {HTTP REFERER}, or if it makes a difference)

Any help/insight is appreciated!

Comment: Are you _really_ sure that you see a _redirection_ ? To me this reads as if you simply look at what the default host of your http server responds to a request to "domainA.com".

Comment: maybe redirect is not quite accurate, I want incoming traffic from domainA to be routed to domainB/page/

Comment: One thing is what you _want_ , another thing is what you _observe_ ... Thanks for clearing up what you _want_ , I asked about what you _observe_ , however. So what happens to the URL visible in your browser if you request `https://domainA.com/`?

Comment: `https://domainA.com/` routs to `https://domainB.com/`

Comment: So the URL in the browser is unchanged? That means your rule does not get applied at all. Since the rule itself is valid (though questionable) there has to be another issue. Maybe you forgot to enable the interpretation of distributed configuration files? Or maybe you implemented the rule at a wrong place? Or maybe the rewriting module is not loaded into your http server? We cannot say...

Comment: Correct. I'm not a server admin, so "Maybe you forgot to enable the interpretation of distributed configuration files" is not understood. Rule is implemented at the top of my .htaccess file on domainB. This is a Plesk server running on Linux if that helps.

Comment: And is that ".htaccess" file actuall interpreted? That _is_ a "distributed configuration file", by the way, those are often called ".htaccess" because it is the default name, that's all. How did you make sure it get's considered?

Comment: In Plesk, there is a way to add a domain and set it to forward to a URL. Using an alias and adding a mod to htaccess was not getting what I wanted. Still learning how to do that, in case I need it in the future.